# Sqlalchemy - rollback when exception

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to rollback a transaction in `core.event 'handle_error' (catch 'KeyboardInterrupt')`, but the parameter in this event is `ExceptionContext`, how do this?

Answer (score 37):

I usually have this kind of pattern when working with sqlalchemy:

```
session = get_the_session_one_way_or_another()

try:
    # do something with the session
except:                   # * see comment below
    session.rollback()
    raise
else:
    session.commit()
```

To make things easier to use, it is useful to have this as a context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def get_session():
    session = get_the_session_one_way_or_another()

    try:
        yield session
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        session.commit()
```

And then:

```
with get_session() as session:
    # do something with the session
```

If an exception is raised within the block, the transaction will be rolled back by the context manager.

---

<sup>*There is an empty `except:` which catches literally everything. That is usually not what you want, but here the exception is always re-raised, so it's fine.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to cath exceptions in handler_error core.event signal

Comment: @SmartElectron OK, but I'm curious, can you explain why you need that approach?

Comment: What if we get exception in `session.commit()` when we are not re-raising the exception?

Comment: @Pranjal An exception in `session.commit()` is not caught, because it is outside the `try` block, so there is no need to re-raise it.

Comment: @zvone That's why, the better way, I think, is to include `session.commit()` in the `try` block itself and not in the else block.

Comment: I don't see a reason to include `commit` in the `try` block. The difference would be that in that case, if `commit` fails, a `rollback` is done instead. To make a decision concerning that, we should know more details - why would a `commit` fail? would the same cause `rollback` to fail as well? I would say proper handling of errors inside `commit` belongs to sqlalchemy code - this code here handles errors in our code.

Comment: With SQLAlchemy 1.4 [you can now use `session.begin()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#framing-out-a-begin-commit-rollback-block) and it will handle commit and rollback automatically. it looks like `with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():`.

Comment: @Thomas Nice, thanks for that info. BTW, this link also confirms that it is correct to have `commit` in `else` block and not in `try` block, as some comments here suggest :)