# SqlAlchemy - pools, sessions, exceptions handling

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-connection

my question revolves around the pool of connections concept and the idea of getting a new connection for each query, BUT in the world of SqlAlchemy.

I have read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232979/sqlalchemy-rollback-when-exception) helpful posts in my research.

I am using alchemy's `Session` in my code. So far I was creating one `Session` instance at an entry point to my code, and I was passing this instance around to places where an actual query would be executed. But I start seeing issues with this approach - specifically when handling exceptions (e.g. rollback, just rolls back everything in the session, not only what specifically went wrong in the last query).

So I would like to stop doing that, and have it rather like this that I start a pool of connections that an entry point to my code, and I'm passing this pool around to places with queries. In such place, I take a connection from the pool, do my stuff, and if something goes wrong, I rollback only this specific connection, and return it to the pool.

My problem is I have no idea how to link all this to the `Session` concept. Does alchemy's `Engine` instance create/manage such pool? Should I think about creating a new `Session` instance as getting a connection from a pool? If so, how do I return a `Session` to an engine? Etc.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

- Does alchemy's Engine instance create/manage such pool?

  - A connection pool is created by default when the engine is created via create_engine (this is configurable via the [pool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool) and [poolclass](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.poolclass) keyword arguments).
- Should I think about creating a new Session instance as getting a connection from a pool?

  - Yes - see [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it)
- [...] how do I return a Session to an engine

  - call the session's [close](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.close) method or in the case of scoped sessions, the [remove](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.remove) method of scoped_session.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's a good strategy/idea/pattern to pass an `Engine` instance to those places/functions where a session would be needed, and be opening and closing a new `Session` instance there?